# How to use crudRespostory in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to  use  crudReposiotry  and connect  to  sql  server,  but  when i try  to  do  this  i  got  this  error:
"Can't make  SessionFactory"

here is  my  code

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import ge.sda.Database.entity.HoliDayEntity;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface HoliDayReposiotry extends CrudRepository<HoliDayEntity, Integer>{
    }
```

application.properties

```
# Server server.port=9008  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://url;servername=cra-test;databaseName=nData
spring.datasource.username=sa spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo
#spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

# Logging logging.level.com.bytestree.restful=DEBUG
```

The `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ge.psda.holiDays</groupId>
    <artifactId>holiDays</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>

        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What  should  i change  to make  this  service  work?

Comment: Posting the full stacktrace would help? And do you have any class configured as `SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: Yeas   i  have   thsi  annotation @SpringBootApplication  on Application  class